# Consulta Linq com count

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Estou fazendo uma consulta que possui alguns joins e um count, porém quero fazer ela com `Linq`.

Está é minha Query.

```
sbSQL.Append("SELECT grproj.cdgruproj as  Id, grproj.dsgruproj as DescricaoGrupoProjeto, ");
            sbSQL.Append("(SELECT COUNT(*) ");
            sbSQL.Append("        FROM usufrm ");
            sbSQL.Append("        WHERE usufrm.cdfrm = form.cdfrm ");
            sbSQL.Append("        AND usufrm.sgproj = proj.sgproj ");
            sbSQL.Append("        AND usufrm.tpproj = tproj.tpproj ");
            sbSQL.Append("        AND usufrm.dtcan IS NULL) as QuantidadeDeUsuarios ");
            sbSQL.Append("FROM grproj  ");
            sbSQL.Append("INNER JOIN proj ON grproj.cdgruproj = proj.cdgruproj ");
            sbSQL.Append("INNER JOIN tproj ON proj.tpproj = tproj.tpproj ");
            sbSQL.Append("INNER JOIN projfr ON proj.sgproj = projfr.sgproj AND proj.tpproj = projfr.tpproj ");
            sbSQL.Append("INNER JOIN form ON form.cdfrm = projfr.cdfrm ");
            sbSQL.Append("WHERE grproj.dtcan IS NULL AND proj.dtcan IS NULL AND form.dtcan IS NULL ");
```

Esse é o exemplo da minha consulta com Linq, o campo quantidade deve ser um count:

```
 IList<GrupoProjetoEntity> grupos = (from grupoProjeto in session.Query<GrupoProjetoEntity>()
                                       join projeto in session.Query<ProjetoEntity>() on grupoProjeto.Id equals projeto.cdgruproj.Id
                                       join tipoProjeto in session.Query<TipoProjetoEntity>() on projeto.tpproj.TipoProjeto equals tipoProjeto.TipoProjeto
                                       join projetoFormulario in session.Query<ProjetoFormularioEntity>() on
                                       new { SiglaProjeto = projeto.sgproj, tpproj = projeto.tpproj.TipoProjeto }
                                       equals new { SiglaProjeto = projetoFormulario.sgproj, tpproj = projetoFormulario.tpproj.TipoProjeto }
                                       join formulario in session.Query<FormularioEntity>() on projetoFormulario.cdfrm.Id equals formulario.Id
                                       select new GrupoProjetoEntity()
                                       {
                                           Id = grupoProjeto.Id,
                                           DescricaoGrupoProjeto = grupoProjeto.DescricaoGrupoProjeto,
                                           QuantidadeDeUsuarios = 0
                                       }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta fazer uma subquery e pegar o `Count` dela:

```
IList<GrupoProjetoEntity> grupos = (from grupoProjeto in session.Query<GrupoProjetoEntity>()
    join projeto in session.Query<ProjetoEntity>() on grupoProjeto.Id equals projeto.cdgruproj.Id
    join tipoProjeto in session.Query<TipoProjetoEntity>() on projeto.tpproj.TipoProjeto equals tipoProjeto.TipoProjeto
    join projetoFormulario in session.Query<ProjetoFormularioEntity>() on
    new { SiglaProjeto = projeto.sgproj, tpproj = projeto.tpproj.TipoProjeto }
    equals new { SiglaProjeto = projetoFormulario.sgproj, tpproj = projetoFormulario.tpproj.TipoProjeto }
    join formulario in session.Query<FormularioEntity>() on projetoFormulario.cdfrm.Id equals formulario.Id
    let contagem = (
                    from usuario in session.Query<UsuarioEntity>()
                    where usuario.cdfrm == formulario.cdfrm
                    where usuario.sgproj = projeto.sgproj
                    where usuario.tpproj = tipoProjeto.tpproj
                    where usuario.dtcan == null
                   ).Count()
    select new GrupoProjetoEntity()
    {
       Id = grupoProjeto.Id,
       DescricaoGrupoProjeto = grupoProjeto.DescricaoGrupoProjeto,
       QuantidadeDeUsuarios = contagem
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Muito boa Miguel, por mais que tenha ficado lenta, a consulta funcionou.

Comment: Que coisa não... tenta usar `let` pra calcular o valor do `Count` antes do `new`... pode ser que ao usar o operador `Count` dentro do `new` ele esteja fazendo vários Count.

Comment: Também pode ver qual é a query que está sendo gerada e executada no banco de dados usando algum profiler de BD.

Comment: Então, a consulta no banco é instantanea, acho que pelo excesso de joins vou tentar usar let e te falo.

Comment: Beleza, se ficar mais rápido eu altero a resposta pra deixar ela o melhor possível.

Comment: COmo seria essa consulta com o let? ele serve para agrupar?

Comment: `let` é só uma variável no meio da query, que pode ser usada depois. Alterei a resposta, mas verifica ai. Se não funcionar eu volto como estava antes.

Comment: Não mudou muita coisa na velocidade, acho que vou partir pra um HQL, ou algo mais rapido. Muito Obrigado Miguel!!

Comment: Como mencionou HQL, suponho que esteja usando o NHibernate. [Existem formas de ver a query que ele está executando no BD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129133/how-do-i-view-the-sql-that-is-generated-by-nhibernate)(está em Inglês)... assim fica mais fácil de saber o que está acontecendo por debaixo dos panos.